# (HTC One M8) No OS and recovery, locked bootloader, how can I flash stock OS on it?

Tags: htc

I've tried to do it for half a year now and I can't find anything that could help. I've already found aproppriate OS for my phone [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/htc-one-m8/help/tutorial-how-to-stock-stock-twrp-t3086860).

Phone info:

(bootloader) version: 0.5

(bootloader) version-bootloader: 3.19.0.0000

(bootloader) version-baseband: 1.29.214500021.12G

(bootloader) version-cpld: None

(bootloader) version-microp: None

(bootloader) version-main:

(bootloader) version-misc: PVT SHIP S-ON

(bootloader) meid: 00000000000000

(bootloader) product: m8_ul

(bootloader) platform: hTCBmsm8974

(bootloader) modelid: 0P6B10000

(bootloader) cidnum: ORANG001

(bootloader) battery-status: good

(bootloader) battery-voltage: 0mV

(bootloader) partition-layout: Generic

(bootloader) security: on

(bootloader) build-mode: SHIP

(bootloader) boot-mode: FASTBOOT

(bootloader) commitno-bootloader: 76df2b54

(bootloader) hbootpreupdate: 11

(bootloader) gencheckpt: 0

Comment: https://www.htc.com/us/support/rom-downloads.html